# Modifying a Wordpress template to show an excerpt with an image

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm modifying my Wordpress template to show an excerpt just below the header with some text, social sharing buttons and a image (kind of a biography).

I have almost all the code but the image doesn't appear. I guess is a pretty simple mistake and someone can help me easily.

Here's my code. Most of the code is copied and adapted to my own theme because I don't know pretty anything about web oriented lenguages like PHP or HTML.

```
<!-- BEGIN .sixteen columns -->
            <div class="sixteen columns">

                <!-- BEGIN .featured-page -->
                <div class="featured-page">




<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Person">

    <!-- BEGIN .eleven columns -->
    <div class="eleven columns">

        **<div class="feature-img iphone-profile"  style="background-image: url(http://www.example.png);"></div>**

        <div class="article">
            <h2 class="title">About me</h2>
            <p>*Some text here*.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="home-social">
            <div class="title">Follow Me</div>
            <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><a class="link-twitter" href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><span aria-hidden="true" class="organicon-twitter"></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="link-linkedin" href="http://pl.linkedin.com/in/" target="_blank"><span aria-hidden="true" class="organicon-linkedin"></span></a></li>
                <li><a class="link-google" href="http://plus.google.com/1" target="_blank"><span aria-hidden="true" class="organicon-googleplus"></span></a></li>
                            <li><a class="link-email" href="example" target="_blank"><span aria-hidden="true" class="organicon-envelop"></span></a></li>
</ul>           </div>

    <!-- END .eleven columns -->
    </div>

    <!-- BEGIN .five columns -->
    <div class="five columns">

        **<div class="feature-img desktop-profile"  style="background-image: url(http://www.example.png);"></div>**

    <!-- END .five columns -->
    </div>

    <span style="display: none;" itemprop="name">Example</span>
    <span style="display: none;" itemprop="organization">Example</span>
    <span style="display: none;" itemprop="role">Example</span>

    <img style="display: none;" itemprop="image"  src="http://example.png" />

</div>



                <!-- END .featured-page -->
                </div>
            </div>
    <!-- END .sixteen columns -->
```

Comment: Which image is not displaying? Can you post the url's for the actual images you are trying to display. Also, on your actual image tag you have `style="display: none;"` try deleting that and see if your image displays.

Comment: The problem was the  style="display: none; as you pointed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome. It would be great if you could accept my answer below then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should try is deleting the `style="display: none;"` in your

```
<img style="display: none;" itemprop="image"  src="http://example.png" />
```

It should look like:

```
<img itemprop="image"  src="http://example.png" />
```